# Error while inflating a DialogFragment : The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android

While trying to inflate a FragmentDialog containing a RecyclerView, I'm having this "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." error.

Here's the code from my DialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private static final String DATA = "data";

    private MyDialogFragment.MyDialogFragmentListener listener;

    private ArrayList<MyArrayList> mArrayListData;

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(ArrayList<MyArrayList> ArrayListData) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();

        args.putParcelableArrayList(DATA, ArrayListData);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getArguments() != null) {

            mArrayListData = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(DATA);

        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());
        builder.setView(createRecyclerView(mArrayListData))
                .setTitle(requireContext().getString(R.string.title))
                .setPositiveButton(requireContext().getString(R.string.ok_button), null);

        Dialog dialog = builder.create();

        /* Option set cause  key board doesn't appear */
        dialog.show();
        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final AlertDialog MyAlertDialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
        if (MyAlertDialog != null) {
            Button positiveButton = MyAlertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ...
                    dismiss();
                    
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            listener = (MyDialogFragment.MyDialogFragmentListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
                    "must implement ExampleDialogListener");
        }
    }

    public interface MyDialogFragmentListener {
        void MyDialogFragmentListenerReturn(ArrayList<MyArrayList> ArrayListData);
    }

    private RecyclerView createRecyclerView(final ArrayList<MyArrayList> ArrayListData){

        LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentLayout, null, false);

        RecyclerView MyRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);
        MyRecyclerAdapter myAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter (getActivity(), ArrayListData);
        MyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        MyRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        myAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onReturnValue(int position, int value) {

                mArrayListData.get(position).setValue(value);
            }

        });

        return MyRecyclerView;
    }
}
```

My recycler adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.InsideRecyclerHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<MyArrayList> mArrayListData;
    private MyRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener mListener;

    MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyArrayList> ArrayListData) {
        mContext = context;
        mArrayListData = RecyclerCarUpdateList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyRecyclerAdapter.InsideRecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View myOwnView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recycler, parent, false);

        return new MyRecyclerAdapter.InsideRecyclerHolder(myOwnView, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerAdapter.InsideRecyclerHolder holder, int position) {

        MyArrayList currentItem = mArrayListData.get(position);

        holder.t1.setText(currentItem.getFirstValue());

        holder.e1.setHint(currentItem.getSecondValue());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArrayListData.size();
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onReturnValue(int position, int newValue);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    static class InsideRecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView t1;
        final EditText e1;

        InsideRecyclerHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener mListener) {
            super(itemView);

            t1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textValue);
            e1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextValue);

            e1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            if (!e1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                listener.onReturnValue(position, Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString()))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4915)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4746)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4718)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:657)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:475)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:233)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:403)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:302)
    at com.myself.myapp.MyDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(MyDialogFragment.java:61)
    at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:419)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1484)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6578)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

It points the issue to the "dialog.show();" of my DialogFragment. I have to admit that I'm quite lost whit is. I have another DialogFragment that works the same way with no issue.

Comment: I tried that in the createRecyclerView function of my DialogFragment:

        `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentLayout, null, false);

        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }`

It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue, I originaly thought it came from my java code but it was an xml layout issue ...

My DialogFrament layout was like that:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#FF8200"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MyDialogFragment ">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewId" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and I just needed to use the RecyclerView as a sole element of the layout:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="#FF8200"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MyDialogFragment "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```